# Is it possible to groupBy a Spark's dataframe when not all values are present in column?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, group-by, missing-data

For example, if I have the following dataframe

```
val tempDF=Seq(("a",2),("b",1),("a",3)).toDF("letter","value")

scala> tempDF.show()
+------+-----+
|letter|value|
+------+-----+
|     a|    2|
|     b|    1|
|     a|    3|
+------+-----+
```

and I want to perform a `groupBy` operation on the column `letter` but knowing that there could be another letter `c` not present in the column `letter`. Normally I would have

```
tempDF.groupBy("letter").sum()

scala> tempDF.groupBy("letter").sum().show()
+------+----------+                                                               
|letter|sum(value)|
+------+----------+
|     a|         5|
|     b|         1|
+------+----------+
```

but I would like something like this:

```
+------+----------+                                                             
|letter|sum(value)|
+------+----------+
|     a|         5|
|     b|         1|
|     c|         0|
+------+----------+
```

Is it possible to do this without somehow adding the letter `c` to the dataframe? What I mean is that I could have many dataframes in a list but I don't know which letters are missing (if any) for each dataframe, instead I do know the whole list of letters that should appear for each one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already know all possible values, create a separate (universal) DataSet with 'value' as 0. 
Then join it with any tempDF to add missing letters. 
Then do groupBy on final dataset.